# Foundation 6 data-animate

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 6. I have a div which I I am using data-toggler to hide/show:

```
<div id="mydiv" data-toggler data-animate="fade-in fade-out">
hide/show me
</div>
```

I don't want to fade-in fade-out, I want it to expand or collapse. My question is: what are all the possible values for data-animate? I can't find this info anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Data toggler is using the motion ui framework. You can find its options and animations [here.](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/motion-ui.html)

The animation you're looking for is probably scale-in-up and scale-out-down.